# Change subject on email sent through contact form in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem, I want to change the subject on the email that we are getting when a customer writes to us through the contact form on a webpage.

I found the line where i change it:

> if (!Mail::Send($this->context->language->id, 'contact',
>   Mail::l('Message from contact form').' [no_sync]',  $var_list,
>   $contact->email, $contact->name, null, null,

I want to change it to

> Mail::l('Message from contact form - customers email')

Anyone know what I need to write there?

I tried like this but it returns 0 in subject:
**Mail::l('Message from contact form' - $contact->email),**

Comment: Try `Mail::l('Message from contact form' . $contact->email)`. The dot `.` is the way to concatenate strings in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf(Mail::l('Message from contact form - %s'), $contact->email)
```

your line will be

```
if (!Mail::Send($this->context->language->id, 'contact', sprintf(Mail::l('Message from contact form - %s'), $contact->email).' [no_sync]', $var_list, $contact->email, $contact->name, null, null,
```

Some details :

[`Mail::l()`](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/3ced84daf906bd4c5924b48948fc75f567fc025a/classes/Mail.php#L598) translates a text in current language, it should be a static text so `Mail::l('Message from contact form' . $contact->email)` is not a good solution.

`Mail::l('Message from contact form' - $contact->email)` can't work, PHP do the operation `'Message from contact form' - $contact->email` before translate so translate 0

`Mail::l('Message from contact form - ') . $contact->email` works but is not a good practice, maybe in an other language the email is not placed at the end. Moreover PrestaShop sucks for translation of text ending by space.

`sprintf(Mail::l('Message from contact form - %s'), $contact->email)` uses a static text 'Message from contact form - %s' and [sprintf](https://php.net/sprintf) replaces %s with customer's email. On an other language, %s can be placed where it should without code modification.

Comment: Hi and thanks alot for your reply! Love when ppl give a good explanation aswell =)

Comment: I think though there is a small problem, when i use the sprintf line i cant translate the subject in BO, it sais HTMLemailtemplates cant contain Javascript code. Also, i did a small change to this line:

Comment: if (!Mail::Send($this->context->language->id, 'contact', sprintf(Mail::l('Message from %s through contact form'), $contact->name), 
       $var_list, $contact->email, $contact->name, null, null,

Comment: but now i get the senders email all the time, not the customers email.

Comment: the error 'Your HTML email templates cannot contain JavaScript code.' is related to the email html content, not the subject https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/af1bc41dd2544cfdd30b162b18845d88e248a4a6/controllers/admin/AdminTranslationsController.php#L1681